# SLIME and Quicklisp not playing nice with each other

Tags: emacs, sbcl, slime, quicklisp

I'm using Emacs as my Common Lisp (SBCL, to be exact) editor, with SLIME. I set up Quicklisp as per the instructions [here](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/#installation), and checked if it worked *outside* of SLIME, and everything was fine - I could grab and download code, include it, everything.

Now, I was trying to use the Compile/Load File command in Emacs for a source file with the following at the top:

```
(ql:quickload "priority-queue")

(defpackage :tournament
  (:use :cl :priority-queue))

(in-package :tournament)
```

Now, once again, *not* in SLIME, this worked fine. However, in SLIME, I get an error of the following form:

```
The name "PRIORITY-QUEUE" does not designate any package.
  [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]
```

Plus a backtrace, of course. Am I missing something in particular? I installed slime using `package-install` from Emacs, and I have the following code in my .emacs file to set it up:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of the separate times of compilation and loading.

When compiling, plain function calls (like `ql:quickload`) are not evaluated. When the compiler tries to process the `defpackage` form (which is *not* a plain function call, but a macro that has side-effects at compile-time), the function that loads "priority-queue" has not been called and the package is not available.

You won't see this if you load the file instead of compiling and loading, because load evaluates each form as it loads.

There are a few options available. The simplest is to wrap your call to `ql:quickload` in `eval-when`, e.g.

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload "priority-queue"))
```

I prefer to define a system for my projects, however small, so I would make a tournament.asd file that looks like this:

```
(asdf:defsystem #:tournament
  :depends-on (#:priority-queue)
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "tournament.lisp")))
```

I'd put that in ~/quicklisp/local-projects/tournament/ (along with tournament.lisp) and use `(ql:quickload "tournament")` in the repl to get started and load it.

I use that latter setup so often that I wrote a Lisp program to do it for me called [quickproject](http://xach.com/lisp/quickproject/).